# Handle PATCH action null values with Symfony ParamConverter

Tags: php, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have a PATCH action in my controller:

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("patchRequest", class="array<App\Model\Request\Product\ProductPatchInternalRequest>", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 * @Patch
 */
public function patchProductsAction(
    array $patchRequest,
    ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors
) {
    if (count($validationErrors) > 0) {
        return $this->view(['errors' => $validationErrors], Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }

    return $this->successNoContent();
}
```

`ProductPatchInternalRequest` model has these attributes: `id` and `brand_id`. Now the problem is that `brand_id` can be passed as null via request and it means that `brand_id` attribute should be set to null.

Now if my JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "brand_id": null
    }
]
```

Then my request object is converted to this array:

```
array:2 [
  0 => App\Model\Request\Product\ProductPatchInternalRequest {#1770
    #id: 10
    #brandId: null
  }
  1 => App\Model\Request\Product\ProductPatchInternalRequest {#1774
    #id: 11
    #brandId: null
  }
]
```

As you can see - first array element has brandId as null even if I didnt't passed it on my request. That's because my request object has this parameter.

I'm looking for a solution which allows me to pass only the data I need to patch, but also have a possibility to set any parameter to null.

Is this possible with ParamConverter?

EDIT:
One of the solutions could be using Symfony Forms with submit action? Like https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-rest/patch-programmer

Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: Since `NULL` is `NULL` and the `ProductPatchInternalRequest::$brandId` property will be  declared as `null` by default, the json data should contain only the values that corelates to all of the object model properties or be excluded from the json data entirely. Requiring the creation of explicit request models to handle the various patch request structures, as opposed to a catch-all. Otherwise you may need to create your own [custom converter](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter) to handle undefined properties

Comment: I wonder what's the return of custom converter should look like? I mean if I return an object, then obviously it will include null parameters even if I didn't passed them on the request.

Comment: The catch-all approach you're proposing is not possible. Since it would not be possible to validate the unknown or abstract structures based on the supplied data. The custom converter would be used to skip converting any objects that do not satisfy the expected data structure of the model. So instead of returning an object that has a default property value of `null` for undefined properties, the offending object(s) would not be in the return result.

Comment: Alternatively, the custom converter could fetch the current values of those that are undefined in the supplied request data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it fully. How can offending objects not be in a returning result if return is an object, which is already predefined with some attributes? And now one of these attributes is missing because it wasn't given in a request. On the other hand I fould a solution which could work - use Symfony forms to submit the request. Like https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-rest/patch-programmer but this way I would have to start using forms in my project instead of ParamConverter. Now I don't know which is a proper way to do it.